# python || В ответ приходят символы

Tags: python, curl

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://www.hero-wars.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.hero-wars.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/91.0.4516.95 (Edition Yx GX)',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not-A.Brand";v="99", "Opera GX";v="91", "Chromium";v="105"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}

params = {
    'js': '1',
}

response = requests.get('https://heroesweb-a.akamaihd.net/wb/v0061/assets/js/world_map_asset/map_asset_002.rsx', params=params, headers=headers)
response.encoding = 'UTF-8'
print(response.text)
```

ответ

RE$X          map_asset_0021.png  p~xڔ�   ��S�����9�y��y�Е����    ��JE(B�T�PJ��&I�P��#zC%S�$IBR�<����s�~ζ�9���?�w���a�����`�1V:Ȯg�Y��0��X������A��Q>c�?���[�Ob��)L�E�!�_<�U`5�>�����O�2������ʸ�6"��R�w��o˲|���'��$V��;����?�rIP��

и так еще 500 строк

Comment: Вы хотите скачать файл? Ибо я так понимаю у этого файл определенная кодировка которую не вы не мы не знаем и просто так прочитать его как человек у нас не получится.

Comment: https://www.file-extension.info/ru/format/rsx возможно этим можно прочитать его